# Which relationship is good to use STI or Polymorphism?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphism, sti

I have read about them but still not clear to me which one I suppose to use and how.
I have User model, Message model and Place model

Message model:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Messages Table:

```
create_table "messages", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :messages
end
```

Users Table:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "password_digest"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "username"
end
```

Now, what I want to do is:
"USER" says "MESSAGES" from "PLACES"

eg. "AHMED" says "HELLO" from "EARTH"

For me both Models (Message and Place) have same data (data type) and same behaviours. So places table should be:

```
create_table "places", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Now may be I'm confused or making big deal than it should be.

What kind of relation should Message and Place have? should it be STI or Polymorphism? 
How should I decide?

I'd appreciate the thinking process of how and why I decide specific association.

Comment: I don't see any logical connection between a message and a place so there's no reason for there to be any relationship between them in code. Just because two things have a string and an integer doesn't mean they have anything useful in common.

Comment: But both belongs to same signed in user, which he/she should fill it's blanks in the view.

Comment: Don't use superficial structure to drive your relationships, model the underlying logic structure instead. A user might have a dog with a name too but that's no reason to force a relationship between dogs and messages is it?

Comment: I was confused should it be STI, Polymorphism or other simpler solution thank I think while I was writing my Q.

Comment: It seems like simple has_many/belongs_to relationships

Answer (score 1):

This example, despite Messages and Places having the same data, doesn't seems a STI/Polymorphism scenario and they should have two different tables.

This could work as a solution:

```
create_table "users" do |t|
  t.string   "username"
end
create_table "messages" do |t|
  t.string   "text"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "place_id"
end
create_table "places" do |t|
  t.string   "name"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
  has_many :places, through: :messages
end

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :place
  def to_s
    "#{user.username} says #{title} from #{place.name}"
  end
end

ahmed = User.new(username: "AHMED")
earth = Place.new(name: "EARTH")
message = Message.new(text: "HELLO", user: ahmed, place: earth)
puts message
# => "AHMED says HELLO from EARTH"
```

Comment: removed some data on migration like `timestamps`, `email` or `password_digest` to keep the focus on the important fields

Comment: Yes i got that, thanks. With that way, users will have_many places through messages, right?

Comment: I'm confused, I have this view:
<%= form_for @message do |form| %>
<p>
I say   
<%= form.text_field :title %>
from 
<%= form.text_field :name %>
<%= form.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
name is a field for place model. I've updated it as:
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :messages
has_many :users, through: :messages
end
I need away to call that 'name' within the form.HOW?

Comment: You should open another question for that.